# How to scrape the data inside a span

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scraping and want to retrieve data from a span however they do not have a class.

They look like this:

```py
"<span content=\"3\">3 - 4 habitaciones</span>", "<span content=\"2\">2 baños</span>", "<span>Desde  89 m²</span>"
"<span content=\"4\">4 baños</span>", "<span>1.300 m²</span>"
"<span content=\"4\">4 baños</span>", "<span>1.300 m²</span>"
```

This is the website https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta
And this is what I am trying to scrape
[scrap this info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npwBA.png)

Some may have all the info:

- habitaciones (rooms),
- baños (bathrooms),

but some do not, I am wondering if there is a way to get each one separately from the scraping stage or if should I do some magic after

```py
def parse(self, response):
    for products in response.css('div.listing.listing-card'):
        yield {
                'name': products.css('div.listing-card__title::text').get(),
                'location': products.css('div.listing-card__location::text').get(),
                'link': products.css('div.listing.listing-card').attrib['data-href'],
                'properties': products.css('span').getall()
            }
```

these yields

```py
"name": "Casa en Venta en Calderón", "location": "Calderón, Quito, Pichincha", "link": "/detalle/14032-32-e7e7-1f62d773dd45-dc2fc640-b378-120d", "properties": ["<span content=\"3\">3 habitaciones</span>", "<span content=\"3\">3 baños</span>", "<span>152 m²</span>"]`
```

And I want the **properties** to be more like **rooms** **bathrooms** and **sqm2**

Comment: create a [mre] or at least post the url for the page

Comment: I have added the website, and what I am looking to scrape in every listing

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can just iterate through each of the property `div`s for each listing `div`, and then you can run use some conditional expression to test if what the property is describing by looking at the icons class description, and then adding the text to the yielded dictionary with the key from the icon description.

For example:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for products in response.css('div.listing.listing-card'):
        item = {
            'name': products.css('div.listing-card__title::text').get(),
            'location': products.css('div.listing-card__location::text').get(),
            'link': products.css('div.listing.listing-card').attrib['data-href']
        }
        for prop in products.css('div.listing-card__property'):
            if prop.css('div.card-icon__area').get():
                item["area"] = prop.css('span::text').get()
            elif prop.css('div.card-icon__bathrooms').get():
                item["bathrooms"] = prop.css('span::text').get()
            elif prop.css('div.card-icon__bedrooms').get():
                item["bedrooms"] = prop.css('span::text').get()
        yield item
```

Or if you wanted to be really clever you could actually skip the if statements and just extract the key directly for the property divs icon class description to get the same results:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for products in response.css('div.listing.listing-card'):
        item = {
            'name': products.css('div.listing-card__title::text').get(),
            'location': products.css('div.listing-card__location::text').get(),
            'link': products.css('div.listing.listing-card').attrib['data-href']
        }
        for prop in products.css('div.listing-card__property'):
            item[prop.xpath('./div/@class').get().split('__')[-1]] = prop.xpath("./span/text()").get()
        yield item
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'name': 'Conjunto Residencial Altamira', 'location': 'Distrito Metropolitano de Quito, Pichincha', 'link': '/proyecto/14032-32-c100-2e2644d36103-24d37585-809a-47ef', 'bedrooms': '2 -
 3 habitaciones', 'bathrooms': '2 - 3 baños', 'area': 'Desde  104 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'San Pio de Pietrelcina', 'location': 'Guayaquil, Guayas', 'link': '/proyecto/14032-32-93a-697855c16d29-d4bad5ea-8795-4935', 'bedrooms': '3 habitaciones', 'bathrooms': '4 bañ
os', 'area': 'Desde  118 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Los Lojas', 'location': 'Los Lojas, Daule, Guayas', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-2315-b5496c787991-fd643c70-8aa8-120d', 'bedrooms': '5 habitaciones', 'bathroo
ms': '5 baños', 'area': '144 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Guayaquil', 'location': 'Guayaquil, Guayas', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-66d3-7be660cb0540-fc65e6e8-ac23-4a87', 'bedrooms': '3 habitaciones', 'bathrooms': '4
,5 baños', 'area': '159 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Departamento en Venta en Quito', 'location': 'Quito, Pichincha', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-9e00-e189ea1d44de-fc52fb5f-a0b8-406d', 'bedrooms': '2 habitaciones', 'bathrooms':
 '3 baños', 'area': '101 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Departamento en Venta en Quito', 'location': 'Quito, Pichincha', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-3afb-450a26e47b70-fa0693ec-bf04-4442', 'bedrooms': '4 habitaciones', 'bathrooms':
 '2 baños', 'area': '344 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Terreno en Venta en Cuenca', 'location': 'Cuenca, Azuay', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-baed-bc973d006d88-f50dc4a7-acce-308c', 'area': '1.755 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en General Vernaza', 'location': 'General Vernaza, Salitre, Guayas', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-e9de-13e2841b36ee-ef522710-8eb0-120d', 'bedrooms': '3 habitacio
nes', 'bathrooms': '3,5 baños', 'area': '152 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Portoviejo', 'location': 'Portoviejo, Manabí', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-3f85-18d8fe00a459-ef4fdde4-9faa-463f', 'bedrooms': '2 habitaciones', 'bathrooms':
'2,5 baños', 'area': '137 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Terreno en Venta en Guayllabamba', 'location': 'Guayllabamba, Quito, Pichincha', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-e954-d1af2422949-e9dadfa0-9438-120d'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Anconcito', 'location': 'Anconcito, Salinas, Santa Elena', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-e944-3104d79522ed-e8bf02a0-bfba-120d', 'area': '420 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Guayaquil', 'location': 'Guayaquil, Guayas', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-4367-1fb3aa53ed81-e85785ef-b912-4c47', 'bedrooms': '3 habitaciones', 'bathrooms': '2
,5 baños', 'area': '200 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Departamento en Venta en Quito', 'location': 'Quito, Pichincha', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-5c8f-db8a03a69e6-e4dddcf8-b0ff-3213', 'bedrooms': '2 habitaciones', 'bathrooms':
'2 baños', 'area': '65 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Terreno en Venta en Tabacundo', 'location': 'Tabacundo, Pedro Moncayo, Pichincha', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-1022-6eea6bb08512-e35450f5-b1a6-41a2'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Departamento en Venta en Quito', 'location': 'Quito, Pichincha', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-7228-df85a4c2b992-e1d7e6b4-a805-4e87', 'bedrooms': '2 habitaciones', 'bathrooms':
 '1 baño', 'area': '55.560 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Guayaquil', 'location': 'Guayaquil, Guayas', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-fe85-1305e21ff6e4-e199f8c1-9631-423f', 'bathrooms': '1 baño', 'area': '105 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Guayaquil', 'location': 'Guayaquil, Guayas', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-c7ba-9a911a65a6ad-e0f3f5a2-b0f6-49b6'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Cuenca', 'location': 'Cuenca, Azuay', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-2835-477f50fcb9d-e0e82005-90c0-484a', 'bedrooms': '5 habitaciones', 'bathrooms': '2 baños',
 'area': '354 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Guayaquil', 'location': 'Guayaquil, Guayas', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-d411-690205fb726c-e00b4f30-a841-120d', 'bedrooms': '3 habitaciones', 'bathrooms': '2
 baños', 'area': '120 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Departamento en Venta en Quito', 'location': 'Quito, Pichincha', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-5934-4f8121111b29-dfc7b8fe-bb17-4cb9', 'bedrooms': '1 habitación', 'bathrooms': '
1 baño', 'area': '36 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Cuenca', 'location': 'Cuenca, Azuay', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-bc13-c159cd97536f-dcd8ce25-ab34-406c', 'area': '380 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Los Lojas', 'location': 'Los Lojas, Daule, Guayas', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-d1b-24ebe8ff2152-db522c3a-bee3-416d', 'bedrooms': '3 habitaciones', 'bathroom
s': '3,5 baños', 'area': '120 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Cuenca', 'location': 'Cuenca, Azuay', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-94e8-556dcdf71a41-d8d648f4-8e63-39a8', 'bedrooms': '36 habitaciones', 'bathrooms': '18 baño
s', 'area': '1.650 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Quito', 'location': 'Quito, Pichincha', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-a9c1-58e4b4ba0790-d6362d4d-a2c8-44b1', 'bedrooms': '3 habitaciones', 'bathrooms': '2,5 ba
ños', 'area': '169 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Local comercial en Venta en Quito', 'location': 'Quito, Pichincha', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-b56-c894b8ba0654-d1264979-a9fd-4414', 'area': '120 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Terreno en Venta en Tenguel', 'location': 'Tenguel, Guayaquil, Guayas', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-7213-821cdfd49ed9-d079cf3d-8ff2-398f', 'bedrooms': '1 habitación', 'bathro
oms': '1 baño', 'area': '160 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Cayambe', 'location': 'Cayambe, Pichincha', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-7952-815d679024b7-cfab17ea-9111-4c5d'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Jadan', 'location': 'Jadan, Azuay', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-c742-bd20679efadd-cfa8cf38-98c0-3549', 'bedrooms': '4 habitaciones', 'bathrooms': '3 baños',
'area': '220 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Departamento en Venta en Guayaquil', 'location': 'Guayaquil, Guayas', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-69ac-7c9ac8abf614-cc4aec92-bf79-4b06', 'bedrooms': '2 habitaciones', 'bathro
oms': '2 baños', 'area': '139 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Departamento en Venta en Guayaquil', 'location': 'Guayaquil, Guayas', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-4a60-de3924004276-cbd2304d-9a6b-4c4e', 'bedrooms': '3 habitaciones', 'bathro
oms': '6 baños', 'area': '261 m²'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Terreno en Venta en Calderón', 'location': 'Calderón, Quito, Pichincha', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-ad6b-ce7536f8d67d-c8e83426-b5d0-494e'}
2023-05-03 12:36:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.properati.com.ec/s/venta>
{'name': 'Casa en Venta en Tenguel', 'location': 'Tenguel, Guayaquil, Guayas', 'link': '/detalle/14032-32-2cbb-378545d5e0df-c879e5b6-80f3-3819', 'bedrooms': '4 habitaciones', 'bathroo
ms': '9 baños', 'area': '420 m²'}
```